# How to set the next/image component to 100% height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a Next.js app, and I need an image that fills the full height of its container while automatically deciding its width based on its aspect ratio.

I have tried the following:

```js
<Image
    src="/deco.svg"
    alt=""
    layout="fill"
/>
```

This snippet compiles successfully, but on the frontend, I see the following error:

> Error: Image with src "/deco.svg" must use "width" and "height" properties or "unsized" property.

This confuses me because according to [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image), these properties are *not* required when using `layout="fill"`.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without manipulating the img position to be relative, or editing the padding on the container from padding top to padding left.

Comment: Which next.js version are you using?

Answer (score 175):

This is what worked for me.

with `next/image`:

```
<div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
  <Image
    alt='Mountains'
    src='/mountains.jpg'
    layout='fill'
    objectFit='contain'
  />
</div>
```

and with `next/future/image`:

```
<Image
    fill
    alt='Mountains'
    src='/mountains.jpg'
    sizes='100vw'/>
```

[next/future/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image)

Comment: Yup, the parent of Image must have `relative` properties.

Comment: you are setting the absolute values for height and width , but the question states in percentage

Comment: I just would like to add something to this answer, In my case, where I needed the image to be aligned to the left, you can add the attribute objectPosition="left"; 
It is passed to css object-position: "left"; 
More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Comment: This is the perfect solution. For those trying this on a card that also has text content, separate the container of the image from the text container and add the `position: relative` to the image container only so it doesn't overlap both the content.

Comment: Check out [next/future/image](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-3#nextfutureimage-component-stable)'s `fill` layout mode that causes the image to fill the parent element.

Comment: With the new next/image - `fill` causes the `object-fit: fill` style to be set. This needs to be overridden in `<Image style={{objectFit: 'contain'}} />`.

Answer (score 163):

**In 2023**, every above solution is deprecated,

use below

```
<Image
  src="url"
  width={0}
  height={0}
  sizes="100vw"
  style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} // optional
/>
```

Github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18474#discussioncomment-5501724

Comment: it's the best or only solution to me

Comment: No need of `sizes="100vw"` attribute. That can be removed. `style` attribute is necessary and not optional.

Comment: this gives a warning:`"Image with src "/images/...png" has either width or height modified, but not the other..."`

Comment: When I omitted `sizes="100vw"`, my images wouldn't load in development. They appeared blurred as if they were partially lazy loaded. Adding this attribute/value pair enabled the images to load completely.

Comment: More upvotes on this answer 

Comment: ```className="w-full h-8"``` // Width 100% and height set to something specific else if height set to 100% or auto, then actual heigh is only 2px.
Adding className instead of style attribute

Comment: This prevents me from applying `placeholder:blur` is there any way around it?

Comment: thank you for your comment!! this was what i was searching for!

Comment: It's  actually bad for layout shift

Comment: I'd recommend using width: auto as well otherwise it'll stretch the smaller images.

Answer (score 33):

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

In NextJS 12 and below

```
<Image src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="100%" height="100%" layout="responsive" objectFit="contain"/>
```

Comment: 100% isn't a valid width - Error: Image with src has invalid "width" property. Expected a numeric value in pixels but received "100%".

Comment: Yes you are right. Overridden with NextJS 13. I hope to find a solution regarding this and update my answer. @OlyDungey

Answer (score 24):

Here is a way:
For example I want to have an image that covers the whole width & height of its container which is a div.

```
<div className={'image-container'}>
  <Image src={path} layout="fill" className={'image'} />
</div>
```

And here is the style:
(There is a container div that occupies half width & height of viewport & my image will cover it.)

```
// Nested Styling
.image-container {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;

    .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative !important;
        object-fit: cover; // Optional
    }
}

// Or Normal Styling
.image-container {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    position: relative;
  }
.image-container .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative !important;
    object-fit: cover; // Optional
}
```

Comment: That is one of the best solution I've found for distant image. For local images, it's way more easier, but for dynamically loaded images this solution is working like a charm.

Comment: None of the solutions I found here work for me.

Comment: There is no need for relative position on image element, so you can remove that!

Comment: @AliRadmanesh my layout broke without it.

Answer (score 14):

And in next v13

```
       <Image
        src={src}
        width={200}
        height={160}
        alt={alt}
        sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw,
              (max-width: 1200px) 50vw,
              33vw"
        style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} //The point is right there!
        //OR className='w-100 h-100'
      />
```

thanks to @Abílio Soares Coelho

Comment: can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed it makes image aspect ratio in a correct way

Answer (score 11):

I think also provide object-fit attribute on the Image element like this:-

```
<Image
    alt="Mountains"
    src="/mountains.jpg"
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="cover"
  />
```

Example provided by Nextjs can be https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/layout-fill.js

Answer (score 5):

```js
    <Image
    src="/deco.svg"
    alt="alternative text"
    fill
    style={{height: "100%", width:"100%"}}
    />
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe these other answers are for a different NextJS version, but none of them worked for me.

I am using NextJS v13.0.0

To accomplish this, I had the following JSX (using TailwindCSS, should be easy to translate to vanilla CSS):

```
<div className="h-screen relative">
  <Image
   src="/image.png"
   alt="pic of dog"
   fill={true}
  />
</div>
```

The important part here is making the parent div's `position: relative` (and setting it's height/width to be what you want for the image) and setting `fill={true}`. I got this from the NextJS Image documentation:

General image documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Documentation on the `fill` attribute: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#fill

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Had to mention fixed height, percentages didn't work for me. This solution worked thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what works with `next/image` in Next 13.5

```
width={0}
height={0}
sizes="100vw"
style={{ width: 'auto', height: '50px' }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Image
    src="/deco.svg"
    alt=""
    width={1000}
    height={1000}
    className='nextimg'
/>
```

in the place where your stylesheet add

```
.nextimg{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

BTW I added 1000 for width and height **when its small amount image gets unclear**. and think you can **add your own styles for nextImg class**

Answer (score 2):

For me in **Next 13** worked fine after I imported the image and moved it away from `public`:

Before

```
<Image src='/link-to-public/img.png' alt="topmoto.pro" />
```

After

```
import img from "../assets/img.png";
...
<Image src={img} alt="topmoto.pro" />
```

Comment: working answer for next 13.2  thank you

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont want to use absolute values for height and width , that is in px etc , you can do something like this

```
    <div style={{ position: "relative", width: "100%", paddingBottom: "20%" }} >
  <Image
    alt="Image Alt"
    src="/image.jpg"
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="contain" // Scale your image down to fit into the container
  />
</div>
```

Original source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358533/12242764

Answer (score 1):

If someone use NextJS with styled components. It works:

```
 const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;

  div, span {
    position: unset !important;
  }

  .image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
  }
`;

      <Container>
            <Image src={ src }
                   layout="fill"
                   className={ "image" }          
            />
        </Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Next 13 when getting images from external URLs you can simply pass fill.

```
import Image from "next/image";

<Image
  src="https://unaqua.com.br/img/logo.png"
  fill
/>
```

Comment: Using a relative parent element with a fixed width and height is required if you want to use `fill`, which is not useful if you don't have a fixed-size parent. \*This is quite useful if you want to have the image as a background.\*

Comment: this also works when using internal assets / images from /public folder

Answer (score 1):

As of Next.js 13.5, adding `layout="responsive"` & adding className and styling in the .css file works

```
<Image
    width={100}
    height={120}
    layout="responsive"
    className="sample_img"
    src="..."
    alt={"Sample Image"}
/>
```

styles.css file:

```
.sample_img{
   max-height: 5rem;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

Once the css is loaded the image changes from `100px * 120px` to `5rem * 5rem` dimensions

Answer (score 1):

### Update2024:  Next 14.6

To make a Image take full height and width of parent add a div wrapper with position relative along with `fill = { true}` in next Image

Working example:

```
<div style={{
                    position: "relative",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                }}>
                    <Image
                        src={project.image_url}
                        alt={`Cover Image for ${project.name} `}
                        style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
                        loading="lazy"
                        fill = { true}
                    />
                </div>
```

Comment: Made my image 0x0.

Answer (score 0):

in Css Changes --->

```
.next-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    div {
        position: unset !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        img {
            position: unset !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            max-height: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
}
```

in JSX Or TSX Component --->>

```
<div className="next-image min-h-[150px]">
          <Image
            src={product?.images?.length ? product?.images[0]?.src : placeholderImage}
            width={imgWidth}
            height={imgHeight}
            layout="responsive"
            loading={imgLoading}
            quality={100}
            alt={product?.title || 'Product Image'}
            className="your Class"
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `layout` property with a value of `fill`, Next.js will automatically set the `position: absolute` and `top:0`, `left:0`, `right:0`, and `bottom:0` CSS properties on the Image component, which makes it fill its container. However, Next.js still needs to know the original dimensions of the image so that it can determine the aspect ratio and resize it accordingly.

You can either provide the width and height properties with the appropriate values, or you can use the unsized property instead, which tells
Next.js to use the original dimensions of the image.

```
<Image  
  src="/deco.svg"
  alt = ""
  layout="fill"
  unsized
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Image with auto height and width. This will display actual size of image.

```js
<Image
  src={selectedImage}
  width={0}
  height={0}
  alt=""
  style={{ width: "auto", height: "100%" }} // optional
/>
```

Image with fixed height and width.

```js
<div style={{ position: "relative", width: "200px", height: "279px" }}>
  <Image
    src={selectedImage}
    fill
    alt=""
    style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}  // As per your requirement
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Next.js 13 or above version, you can try like this.

```
<div className="b relative h-[300px] w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg" key={idx}>
    <Image fill src={src} alt='img' className="w-full object-cover" />
</div>
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

works for me

```
<div
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: 'auto',
    maxHeight: 343,
    position: 'relative'
  }}
>
  <Image
    src={`<YOU_IMAGE>`}
    alt="thumbnail"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    layout="responsive"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: What does `height: 'auth'` mean?

Comment: @Jake I'm guessing they meant `height: 'auto'`

Comment: A value of 100% isn't valid for NextJS 13 - Error: Image with src has invalid "width" property. Expected a numeric value in pixels but received "100%".

Answer (score -1):

Working with **Next 14** and Tailwind css

```
        <div className=" w-full h-full relative">
        <Image
            src={'/url'}
            alt=" "
            fill={true}
            objectFit="cover"
        />
        </div>
```

`w-full h-full` takes the width and height of a parent and can be replaced with the actual dimensions you want the image to follow.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */` as the top of file.
Worked! it is happening as <img src needs to be replaced by  as provided by next.js

Comment: I feel like this is silencing the issue rather than finding an actual solution, no?

Answer (score -3):

It works for me in next.js image component

```
<Image src="/path/image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="100%" height="100%" layout="responsive" objectFit="cover"/>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, attributes `width="100%" height="100%"` don't seem to have valid values

Comment: It doesn't work