# NextJs Image component with auto height

Tags: next.js

In Next.js app, am using Image component. I want to load an image with auto height and width.

```
 <div style={{ height:'',width:'' }}>
    <Image 
       src={imgLink}
       objectFit="cover"
       layout="fill"
    />
 </div>
```

I can easily achieve this if i can specify height and width in its parent div. but what i want is to load it in its natural height. Is there something am missing ?

I found a similar question in stackoverflow.
[How to use Image component in Next.js with unknown width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353475/how-to-use-image-component-in-next-js-with-unknown-width-and-height)
.But no success. Isn't there any other way to achieve this ? should I need to stick with img?