# How to size images by height and auto width with NextJS Image Component

Tags: css, image, next.js

I have images that I would like to have a fixed pixel height and auto width with `object-fit: contain`.

How does one achieve this behavior with NextJS Image Component? I'd like to avoid `layout="fill"` as I would like the intrinsic width of the image (`width: auto`).

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"/>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/236/300/300"/>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/300/100"/>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/250/275"/>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/400/100"/>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/300/300"/>
<div/>
```

The following does NOT work as the above with NextJS Image component:

```js
  <div className="wrapper">
     <div className="image-wrapper">
        <Image
          layout="responsive"
          width={image.width}
          height={image.height}
          src={image.src}
          objectFit="contain"
         />
     <div/>
     <div className="image-wrapper">
        <Image
          layout="responsive"
          width={image.width}
          height={image.height}
          src={image.src}
          objectFit="contain"
         />
     <div/>
  </div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I think you should swap your snippet out for the NextJS image setup you have

Comment: Also, *why* would you like to avoid `layout=fill`?

Comment: If I can achieve the intrinsic width with `layout="fill", then that would be fine. I don't see a way of making that happen though.

Comment: It seems like what you want isn't implemented yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353475/how-to-use-image-component-in-next-js-with-unknown-width-and-height

Comment: Maybe try on the `.wrapper { width: min-content }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NextJS Image Component experimental support for "Raw" layout provided me with what I needed to achieve this.

**UPDATE**: Experimental Raw layout is now [next/future/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image)

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35493

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.w-auto {
  width: auto;
}

.max-w-none {
  max-width: none;
}

.object-contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
   <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="img-wrapper">
   <Image
      className="h-full w-auto max-w-none object-contain"
      alt={logo?.ariaLabel}
      src={src}
      layout="raw"
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </div>
<div/>
```

Comment: This answer is now obsolete with the raw feature being moved to a new module `next/future/image`. Please consider updating it.