# Why do I have to use style= to get the height and width to work in next/image?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

```
import Image from 'next/image';
    
<Image src={meuItem.ImageUrl} 
width={310} 
height={260} 
style={{ width: '310px', height: '260px' }} />
```

For some reason it seems like the next/image component from nextjs doesn't respect the width and height property.

The only way I could get it to work was to add a style property and set the width and the height with that.

It's strange becuase if I remove the the properties from the Image component, nextjs throughs an error, saying that it is expecting those properties.

So if you have to put them in, then why doesn't it actually apply them?

Comment: As next.js is SSR, `Image` works differently from an ordinary image in React. You can have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169431/how-to-set-the-next-image-component-to-100-height

Comment: What version are you using? There were changes to `next/image` in v13