# I'm using next js , next Image and the images are not showing when i opened the inspector the images had 0 height , any thoughts?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, nextjs-image

```
this is the code for the grid that contains the photos : 



 <div className="w-full h-full">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-start items-center h-full w-full gap-4 py-4 ">
          <div className=" w-[70%] h-[60%] grid grid-cols md:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-3  grid-cols-1 gap-y-6 gap-x-6 py-14 ">
            <div className="relative w-full h-full">
              <Image
                src={`https://himenobaraen.jp/wp-content/uploads/rosa_chinensis.jpg`}
                alt="image"
                unoptimized={true}
                fill={true}
                className="object-cover"
              />
            </div>
     </div>
```

i tried to give it a height in pixels but i cant give it a specific height because i need it to be responsive , what can i do ?

Comment: i found the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76008677/22773671)**

Answer (score 0):

As per [enter link description here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image)nextjs/image component document, you need to provide either of the properties from

- fill or
- width/height

Comment: i found the answer ty. @prashant-shah

Comment: @Moenatos, Can you tell what it is so others can take reference of that over here and also if you find the answer helpful then at least upvote it.

Comment: I added a comment to my question since i can't answer or upvote an answer , and i provided a link in the comment for the solution. @prashant-shah